# How to search for hotel rooms with suites (two or more rooms joined together) on Booking.com?

Tags: accommodation, booking.com

I tried to book two *private* (not dormitory beds) and *independent* (not twin or double rooms) rooms on [booking.com](https://booking.com). I am able to filter out the private room by clicking **"Show private rooms only"**, as shown below.

[image]

However, the results contain a lot of twin or double rooms, as shown below.

[image]

It is wired as I set `Rooms` to `2` in the left search area.

How do I filter out two independent or separated rooms?

Comment: Are you looking for a suite with two bedrooms?  Or two rooms with a connecting door?  Or something else?

Comment: A twin or double room may be the smallest room some hotels offer - they are still private, and you wouldnt be expected to share, you book the entire room.

Comment: @Tom, both of them are OK. I mean each of us prefers a private space (separate with each other with a door).

Comment: @Moo, I see. but it is still a **room** with two separated beds.

Comment: Suites are not cheap, as they usually are geared toward business folks with bedrooms and a common sitting room.  You might be better served with a connecting room so you can visit without going outside into the hall.  Most though will be a double bed in one room, twin beds in the other room (family oriented)

Comment: @sparkandshine as Tom says, you want a suite - the "rooms" you are searching for is not "rooms in the suite" its "number of separate bookings I want to make" (essentially), in that you get two entirely independent rooms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the results - many hotels only have twins or doubles as their smallest room, you simply book two of them.  They are private and non-shared, they are not dormitory or hostel style rooms.

You are getting what you are searching for.

The OP has clarified through comments that they are actually after a suite with several rooms, which that search option has nothing to do with - that option merely filters out hotels which do not have the right availability for your dates (there is no point in showing you a hotel if they only have one room available).